# Filter an Arraylist of object based on the most common value of an attribute of the object in Java

Tags: java, object, variables, arraylist, filter

I am trying to filter an ArrayList of a Java Object based on the value of the variable of the object.

I'm sorry if it sounds confusing. Maybe the code will explain it better.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    ArrayList<Data> list = new ArrayList<>();

    list.add(new Data("Uvumvew", 10));
    list.add(new Data("Uvumvew", 10));
    list.add(new Data("Uvumvew", 10));
    list.add(new Data("Uvumvew", 11));
    list.add(new Data("Uvumvew", 14));
    list.add(new Data("Uvumvew", 14));
    list.add(new Data("Ossas", 5));
    list.add(new Data("Ossas", 5));
    list.add(new Data("Ossas", 10));
    list.add(new Data("Ossas", 10));
    list.add(new Data("Ossas", 10));
    list.add(new Data("Dummy", 7));
    list.add(new Data("Dummy", 7));
    list.add(new Data("Dummy", 7));
    list.add(new Data("Dummy", 8));
    list.add(new Data("Dummy", 8));
}
```

and the Object

```
private String name;
private double value;

public Data() {
}

public Data(String name, double value) {
    super();
    this.name = name;
    this.value = value;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public double getValue() {
    return value;
}

public void setValue(double value) {
    this.value = value;
}
```

There will be duplicates in the arraylist as you can see. I can only filter it after it being an arraylist since I'm reading files then putting it into the ArrayList.

The output I'm trying to achieve look like this

```
Uvumvew,10
Ossas,10
Dummy,7
```

Since 10,10,7 are the most common value for Uvumvew,Ossas,and Dummy respectively. I have tried using Collection and to filter the value but as there contains duplicate values among the Object, it is not possible.

My attempt is like this

```
Collection<Data> nonDuplicatedName = list.stream()
               .<Map<String, Data>> collect(HashMap::new,(m,e)->m.put(e.getName(), e), Map::putAll)
               .values();
```

it produce a output like this which is wrong

```
Dummy 8.0
Uvumvew 14.0
Ossas 10.0
```

Any help or correction to my understanding would be appreciated. Thanks !

Comment: post your attempted code for the problem

Comment: There may be a way to use streams to do this, or you could construct a Map of values to counts, then checking which is the mode

Comment: Implement `hashCode()` and `equals()` on your `Data` class and then use a `Set<Data>` instead of an `ArrayList`.

Comment: i added my attempt. Please correct me if it is wrong

Comment: @AntonBalaniuc thanks for the answer.. I already tried finding the distinct value but I needed to find the most common value of the Object.

Comment: @SeanBright I too, was thinking of a Set at first, until I saw they wanted a specific element to be kept (the mode, not the first)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might be a bit over-complicated and there is an overhead of using intermediate map, but this should solve your problem:

```
Map<String, Map<Double,Long>> tmpMap = list.stream()
        .collect(
                groupingBy(Data::getName,
                        groupingBy(Data::getValue,counting())
                ));
// {Dummy={8.0=2, 7.0=3}, Ossas={10.0=3, 5.0=2}, Uvumvew={10.0=3, 11.0=1, 14.0=2}}
```

Let's count frequency of `Data#value` in the original first. So we just group by `Data#name` fist, to get a map of similar objects and after this we group by `Data#value` and counting at the same time how many times individual `value` is present. This will give us a `Map` where `keys` are `Data#names` and `values` frequency of `Data#values` `Uvumvew={10.0=3, 11.0=1, 14.0=2}`
Now having this map we can create a new `Data` objects with most frequent value - by just to iterating over `tmpMap` and constructing new objects using `Map#key` as `Data#name` and maximum element from nested frequency map `{10.0=3, 11.0=1, 14.0=2}` as `Data#value`

```
tmpMap.entrySet()
        .stream()
        .map(
                entry -> new Data(
                        entry.getKey(),
                        entry.getValue().entrySet().stream()
                                .max(Map.Entry.comparingByValue()).get().getKey()
                )
        ).collect(toList()); 
//[Data{name='Dummy', value=7.0}, Data{name='Ossas', value=10.0}, Data{name='Uvumvew', value=10.0}]
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. I understand the concept clearly ! :D However, the counting() and toList() method returns an error. Is there something I have to import or JDK change ??

Comment: @SmileyHuehue, you are welcome. Yes, you need to import Collectors: `import static java.util.stream.Collectors.*;` Please don't forget to accept this answer as right one if you find it useful